# Creating Windows Installation Media or Facsimile

Tags: windows-server-2003, media

I have a Windows 2003 server 64-bit. It has a legitimate license, and is registered. I do not have the installation media that was used to install the server. I need to put IIS on the server. Is there a way to do that, and, if so, how?

I believe there are links on Microsoft's site, but I'm not sure where these are or what they are called. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the specific disc that came with your server per se.  Instead as long as you have a disc that has the type of OS your server has on it you should be able to use it to load the required features.

By type I mean the license type: OEM, VLA, etc.  Although the type may not actually matter for installing IIS.

There may be alternative means to acquire a 2003 x64 ISO but I would not recommend them here as SysAdmins should only be using discs that they can ensure are clean and from a vendor or reliable source.  I also don't think there are any work arounds to install IIS with any files on the HDD already.  Prior to 2008 features had to be loaded from the disc.

> If you have TechNet or MSDN access you should be able to go download
>   an ISO for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact the vendor that you purchased the Windows license from originally. As long as your license is legitimate, they should be able to help you obtain a legal copy of the media.